# Al subir archivo de extensión erronea en PHP no muestra el mensaje de error definido

Tags: php, upload

Tengo un formulario para enviar un archivo y en el documento que lo recibe tengo este pedazo de código. El archivo debe ser `.pdf`, y si no lo es, pues debería mostrar el mensaje de que es incorrecto. Pero **me lleva directamente al formulario de nuevo**. Eso sí, el archivo no lo sube.

El código sube el archivo con el nombre `novas.pdf` pero comprueba si ya existe dicho nombre y si es así renombra el existente a `novas_anteriores.pdf` y luego sube `novas.pdf`.  Funciona correctamente salvo en el caso de que no sea `.pdf`, que no muestra el mensaje.

```
$targetfolder = "../Subidas/";    
$targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name'] ) ;
$ok = 1;
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

if( $file_type !== "application/pdf" ) {
  echo "ATENCIÓN: Só se permiten arquivos PDF.<br>";
  exit;
} else { 
  if( file_exists( '../Subidas/novas.pdf' ) ) {
    rename( "../Subidas/novas.pdf", "../Subidas/novas_anteriores.pdf" );
  }

  if( $_FILES['file']["error"] > 0 ) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES['file']['error'] . "<br>";
  } else {
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"../Subidas/novas.pdf" );
    echo "Arquivo Subido Correctamente.";
  }
}
```

Comment: Perdón si se ve "raro" el código. Lo he editado varias veces pero me lo pega así.

Comment: Pongo una captura de imagen por si se ve más claro.

Comment: Las capturas no están muy bien vistas en el sitio; de echo, se está planteando **prohibirlas** a los nuevos usuarios. Para formatear el código, `Ctrl + k` Es tu amigo ;-)

Comment: La lógica está mal planteada, es redundante. Mediante esto: `if( file_exists( '../Subidas/novas.pdf' ) ) {` determinas dos cosas: 1º. si e archivo existe, 2º. si tiene la extensión `.pdf`. Por tanto, esto está de más: `if( $file_type !== "application/pdf" ) {` en cambio, puedes controlar mediante el `input` que recoge el archivo en el HTML que sólo acepte archivos del tipo `.pdf`

Comment: Gracias Trauma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vemos la estructura de tu código:

```
if( ) {
  echo ... ;
  exit;
} else {
  if( ) {
    echo ... ;
  } else {
    echo ... ;
  }
```

Y, según dices, **todos los `echo` funcionan menos el primero**, parece que el problema está en ese `exit`. Sentencia redundante e inútil, ya que la estructura de tus `if( )` provocará que ese `echo` sea lo único que se ejecute en ese caso concreto.

Elimina pues ese `exit` problemático:

```
if( $file_type !== "application/pdf" ) {
  echo "ATENCIÓN: Só se permiten arquivos PDF.<br>";
} else {
  ...
```

Comment: Además esa evaluación `if( $file_type !== "application/pdf" ) {` no tiene ningún sentido. Si se analiza la lógica del programa, vemos que hay que validar si existe un archivo con el nombre `novas.pdf`. Si pasa esa validación, tiene las dos cosas hechas: 1) el archivo tiene la extensión `.pdf`; 2) el archivo se llama `novas.pdf`. Siempre es bueno cuando hay muchas evaluaciones pensar **¿cuál debe ir primero?**, así determinas a veces que tienes evaluaciones de más, porque simplemente no las pusiste en el orden de prioridad (este caso es un claro ejemplo de ello).

Comment: Lo siento, pero no entiendo tu lógica. `file_exists( )` comprueba si el archivo existe en local. ¿ Como le beneficia el saber que **en algún momento del pasado** se realizó una subida correcta ?

Comment: Trauma. He probado a eliminar el exiit y me hace exactamente lo mismo. Me devuelve a la página del formulario sin mostrar el aviso "ATENCIÓN: .... ". :-(

Comment: A. Cedano, creo que la lógica está bien, me explico. Primero se comprueba si el archivo es de tipo pdf y si no lo es ya no se mira si existe o no novas.pdf y no se guarda dicho archivo. Si es pdf es cuando se comprueba si hay un archivo anterior novas.pdf (ya sabiendo que el archivo que se intenta subir es un pdf), si existe este archivo anterior se renombra a novas_anteior.pdf y el nuevo se sube como novas.pdf.

Comment: @BruxotoloTolo Pues, sinceramente, ya no se que decirte. ¿ Los demás `echo` funcionan correctamente ? ¿ Puedes poner algo mas de código **después** del que muestras ?

Comment: Es el único código en esa página, a no ser unos includes iniciales que aseguran que no se pueda acceder sin iniciar sesión, pero no tienen por qué afectar.

Comment: La página que llama a la que tiene ese código tiene el formulario:
<form action="subir.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Engadir" />

y sí, el echo que muestra el mensaje "Arquivo Subido Correctamente." cuando se sube un pdf sí que se muestra.

Comment: @BruxotoloTolo No se, todo parece correcto ... No se que mas decirte, lo siento :-(

Comment: Simplifiqué tanto el documento que tiene el formulario como el que tiene el código de subirlo y funciona perfectamente. No entiendo por qué razón con los includes de control de usuario y demás código html que forma la página no muestra ese echo. Ya digo que poniendo un .html con el formulario y un php sólo con el código mostrado funciona... tendré que investigar... MUCHAS gracias. –

Comment: @BruxotoloTolo Investiga por si en alguna parte cambias el código de salida, usando `http_response_code( )` o `header( )`.  Por decirte algo, vamos :-)

Comment: Pues no estoy seguro de que he hecho pero ahora funciona. Eso sí, siguiendo tu recomendación de no poner el exit. Pero realmente no he cambiado nada más que sea importante. Me da que antes no iba (después de eliminar el exit) por algún tema de cache. Gracias por todo.

Comment: @BruxotoloTolo Pues también pudiera ser O_o Bueno, me alegro de que lo pudieras resolver :-)

Comment: @BruxotoloTolo no tiene sentido preguntar primero si es un `pdf` para luego preguntar si ese pdf se llama `novas.pdf`. Puedes preguntar directamente si se llama `novas.pdf` o no, porque el código en sí dependerá de eso. Dicho de otro modo, si el archivo se llama `novas.pdf` ya tendrás hechas las dos validaciones en una. Me parece totalmente lógico.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que comentas, el fallo parece estar en esta línea:

> ```
> if( $file_type !== "application/pdf" ) {
> ```

Prueba con `!=` en vez de `!==`:

```
if( $file_type != "application/pdf" ) {
```

En este enlace tienes más información sobre los operadores:

http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php